# Execute SQL query on Oracle working in Unix prompt but not in shell script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ksh

I am trying to connect to an Oracle db using a ksh script. When I run this directly from the prompt, it works. But when I put it inside a script (abc.sh) it fails. Below is what I've put in the script (edited to make it shorter):

Here abc is the username, while abc$123 is the password of the user which has access on database DBNAME.

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh

 sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF > output
 connect abc/abc$123@DBNAME;

 set echo off
 set heading off

 select table_name from dba_tables;
 exit;
 EOF
```

This works if typed directly, but run as ./abc.sh, gives error -

```
 ERROR ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't figure this out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just write code like this and expect it to be passed to the relevant program. Your SQL lines are being executed by KSH instead of your SQL server. Instead you need to do something more along the lines of:

```
echo "SQL CODE HERE" | sqlplus ....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I changed it to read:
      sqlplus -s /nolog @abc.sql

where abc.sql had the connect and select queries. Working great now.

Comment: Thanks Velox. It helped me too. I was searching for this for past 1 hour.